# Start Zathura at Specific Location on Screen

Tags: zathura

I would like to edit my zathurarc so that zathura opens at a specific location on my screen every time I open a pdf. What command do I need to put into the zathurarc file to achieve this? I have set the window dimensions to my specifications but I would like the location of the window to be specified as well.